# Gradient Fill an Annotation on a Time Series Chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `ggplot2`, I'd like to add an `annotate()` shape to a time-series plot based on date specifications, then gradiently fill the shape left-to-right from "gray90" to "gray50". Below is a minimum-working example:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(813)
min_date = as.Date("2020-05-01")
max_date = as.Date("2020-07-14")
dates = seq(min_date, max_date, by = "day")
shaded_start = max_date - 21

df <- data.frame(dates = dates,
                 volumes = runif(length(dates)))

chart <- ggplot(df, aes(x = dates, y = volumes)) +
    geom_line() +
    annotate("rect", xmin = shaded_start, xmax = max_date + 2,
       ymin = 0, ymax = Inf, alpha = .4) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "gray90", high = "gray55")

chart
```

[image]

As you can see, the gray shaded area is a single color of gray instead of gradiently filled. I'm open to using something other than `annotate()`, like `geom_rect()` or `geom_raster()`, but I haven't been able to figure it out with either of those options yet either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no native way to do a gradient fill in `ggplot`. Each element can only take a uniform fill. However, it's entirely possible to make it look as though you have a gradient fill by creating a bunch of gradually-changing strips:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(813)
min_date = as.Date("2020-05-01")
max_date = as.Date("2020-07-14")
dates = seq(min_date, max_date, by = "day")
shaded_start = max_date - 21

lefts <- seq(shaded_start, max_date, 0.5)
rights <- c(lefts[-1], max_date + 0.5)
maxs <- rep(Inf, length(lefts))
mins <- rep(-Inf, length(lefts))
fill <- seq(0, 1, length.out = length(lefts))
shade_df <- data.frame(lefts, rights, maxs, mins, fill)

df <- data.frame(dates = dates,
                 volumes = runif(length(dates)))

chart <- ggplot(df, aes(x = dates, y = volumes)) +
  geom_rect(data = shade_df, inherit.aes = FALSE,
            aes(xmin = lefts, xmax = rights, ymin = mins, ymax = maxs, fill = fill),
            colour = NA, size = 0) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "gray90", high = "gray55") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

chart
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `geom_tile` and subsetting the initial data:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = dates, y = volumes)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_tile(data = subset(df, df$dates >= shaded_start),
            aes(x = dates, y = 0.5, fill = as.numeric(dates)),
            alpha = 0.6, height = 1.2, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "gray90", high = "gray55")
```

[image]